# Custom keyboard on UITextView shows apple keyboard first then switches to the custom keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, swift4

Short video of what happens when tapping on a textView:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LG_r3iDJKiM

I'm trying to show my custom keyboard on a UITextView from the textViewDidBeginEditing function, The custom keyboard has been tested on UITextFields and is working as intended. Now I'm trying to get the same keyboard to work with UITextViews.
When opening the app for the first time, and tapping on a textView the first time will have this behavior, then when we tap on other textViews the custom keyboard is there directly as intended.

the Current code in my TextViewDidBeginEditing, I tried changing the order of the last 4 lines but with no success:

```
public func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
   keyboard = Keyboard.sharedInstance.keyboardWithType(availableKeyboards.numbers.rawValue, returnKey:textView.returnKeyType, isSecure: false,decimalSeparator:self.decimalSeparatorCharacter, responderClass: self)

   inputView.keyboardAppearance = .dark
   inputView.hideAssistantBar()
   inputView.inputView = keyboard
   inputView.reloadInputViews()
}
```

This will result in the video above, I tried some other ways but no success yet:

Setting a empty UIView as the inputView, this will still result in the apple keyboard shortly appearing

```
let view:UIView = UIView()
textView.inputView = view
```

also tried doing reloadInputViews but that doesn't work either:

```
textView.reloadInputViews()
```

also tried running it all on the main tread with

```
DispatchQueue.main.async { }
```

but no success, I cannot understand why even setting a UIView() as the inputView will still shortly show the apple keyboard. Any help in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than set the `inputView` in `textViewDidBeginEditing`, set the `inputView` just after creating the `UITextView`.

Comment: I'm creating a cocoapod for a large Objc project, I really need a way to do this without having to add this line on every textView :s

Comment: Showing the code for creating/configuring the `UITextView` will help answer the question. You could create a method to create/configure that returns a `UITextView`, or create a custom `UITextView` with an initializer that takes a custom input view as a parameter and assign it to the `UITextView`.